# Recursive method not working properly in grails/groovy unit test case

Tags: grails, recursion, groovy, testcase

*MyService.class*

```
public boolean myMethod1() {
    boolean success = false
    for (1..2) {
        success = myMethod2()
    }
    return success
}

public boolean myMethod2() {
    int value = otherService.someMethod() // mocked this method call
    boolean saved = false
    try {
        // trying to persist value
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        if (someCondition)
            myMethod2() // comes back here instead of going to the method called :  "Problem line"
    }
    return saved
}
```

I have a test case which has mocked `otherService.someMethod()` to return different result for every execution of it. 
Using groovy way not grails Grails bug - http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4611

When there is a validation exception and upon certain condition i want to call `myMethod2()` recursively to get a new output for saving data.
mocked method closure will return a output in such a way that the first pass will return int, which will internally return (true/false) back to the `myMethod1()`. 
Next(from the loop) time when the `otherService.someMethod()` is called it will return an output which will cause a `validationException` and 
it will call the same method for new output. Now when the mocked method is called for the 3rd time, the mocked 
output will return a different value which will not cause validationException. After executing try block,
it comes to the return statement of `myMethod2()` but it goes back to "Problem line" instead of going back to `myMethod1()`, the one who invoked it.

How to make the test case to call back to `myMethod1()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought when the `return saved` is called it would go to the parent api who invoked it. But according to the stack (thread) it goes to the `:Problem Line`.

What i did was, in the catch block, instead of calling just `myMethod2()` I modified it to `return myMethod2()`

It eventually returned `true/false` according to the business logic. And the test case also passed.

Thanks for your input dmahapatro

Answer (score 1):

Think like this, I am travelling in a train, I stood up from my seat and walked from one compartment to the another through the interconnection and to another and to another. So now I am in the 4th compartment of the train. If I want to return back to my seat which is in the 1st compartment I have to walk all the way back from 4th to 3rd to 2nd to 1st because I cannot jump from 4th compartment to the 1st one directly(unless I am Hulk or Iron Man and on top of the train). Similar concept holds good in method calls.

`method1()` calls `method2()` calls `method2()` calls `method2()`.

while `return` a value from the last method the control should trace back in the reverse order. So in order to return back to `method1()` you have to have a success condition checked to return back to the caller, some thing like this:

```
public boolean myMethod2() {

    int value = otherService.someMethod() // mocked this method call
    boolean saved = false
    try {
        // trying to persist value
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        if (someCondition){
            myMethod2() // comes back here instead of going to the method called :  "Problem line"
            if(some value satisfied){
                 return // return to caller with true or false or whatever according to your need
             }
        }
    }
    return saved
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I modified my code and I have given my answer below.